# JOIN на уровне базы данных или на уровне приложения?

Tags: java, sql, база-данных, hibernate

Имется две таблицы: Судья и Соревнование. Одно соревнование судят несколько судей, один и тот же судья может судить несколько соревнований. Необходимо получить судью по имени и названию соревнования.

В комментарии к одной из статей увидел следующий вариант: делаются отдельные выборки из двух таблиц, а на уровне приложения происходит их склеивание (поиск необходимого судьи). Или лучше сразу сделать запрос с JOIN?

Какой вариант будет приемлем если:

1. Таблицы находятся в одной базе данных;
2. Таблицы находятся в разных базах данных.

Comment: Разумеется сразу делать join в базе - это гораздо менее ресурсоёмко. И даже если таблицы находятся в разных базах - тоже джойнить в базе, это по-прежнему менее ресурсоёмко. SQL server (я смотрю на теги вопроса, которые вы указали) поддерживает запросы между базами и между серверами. Но я недоумеваю: зачем разделять таблицы по разным базам? Положите их в одну.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Или лучше сразу сделать запрос с JOIN?

Если есть такая возможность, то **да**. Это будет и быстрее и менее ресурсоемко.
Очевидно, что в 1ом случае сделать **join** можно без проблем. Во 2ом - все зависит от конкретной БД (поддерживает ли она запросы к таблицам другой БД, например, в Oracle DB можно создать dblink и с помощью него обращаться к объектам другой БД) .

Comment: Кстати, тип базы-то мы так и не узнали...

Comment: В моем вопросе я хотел узнать картину в общем. Поэтому не привязывался к конкретной базе данных.